# Multiple call using asterisk dialplan

Tags: php, asterisk

I want to make multiple calls at the same time using using sip dialplan, like :

```
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/${DIAL}${DIALSTR})
```

while, in my dial variable there are multiple numbers like and there context is this way:

```
local/11111111111&local/33333333333&local/5555555555&local/777777777777@scl_local
```

I want to call all the numbers at the same time, so I created context above; but that called  only one number and got disconnected.

I want to dial something like this:

```
SIP/11111111111,33333333333,5555555555,777777777777
```

Answer (score 1):

Dial(SIP/101&SIP/102&SIP/103)

Answer (score 0):

the above dialplan dials all the number mentioned simultaneously , whoever picks first the call will be connected and the rest will be disconected.

Comment: yes u r right but i want to call all number at a time bcoz i have lot of number and no call can be disconnected so any idea how to achive this one...